# jQuery five star display rates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im working on project to display rate on some field and I'm already get the rate for this field from the server like `"60%"` or `"50%"` and so on...

I don't know if there any jQuery plugin can help just to display the rate without clicking feature,

something like

```
var rate = "60%";
jQuery.setRate(rate); // or something like this
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. Please add more detail explaining what exactly you are trying to accomplish and what your attempt has yielded so far. That way, we will actually be able to give you useful feedback and assistance.

Comment: Something like: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/4aMsL/

Comment: Why was the question closed? It's clear for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesonally i dont think you need a plugin todo that, you can just show a Different image according the rate you get from db.

First, remove non numeric chars, just to get the integer(numeric) value.
After that, you just have to create your Rules for the different starts image(?)

```
var sImageUrl="";

if (rate >0 && rate =<10) sImageUrl="/[yourUrl]/imageStars_1.jpg";
if (rate >10 && rate =<20) sImageUrl="/[yourUrl]/imageStars_2.jpg";
...
```

well, if you consider not to add a plugin, if you only want to show the results, maybe you can even not do that on client site and "process" this image choice on serverside (as other option)...

Comment: An efficient way might be to use sprites (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). That way, you only load a single image file. You should be able to position the sprite from the percentage using a single line of code if you think about it...

Comment: Even better do a modulus the number of images you have: `rate%NUMBER_OF_IMAGES` and use that number for displaying. And I guess adding a specific class to the displaying element would be the right way to do it, like: `stars_3`.

Comment: @arxanas: sorry for bad typing, i mean <= 10

Comment: Thanks, I found that i don't even need jQuery it can be done by css and simple javascript command :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that's also clickable the raty plugin is really awesome and works very well even with no well formatted data (meaning it will take a 4.7 and round it to 5 stars etc): [raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty).